# Tableview to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a controller named as "firstViewcontroller" where i have a `UITableView` named as "discoveredInstanceTableView". I want to load that `UITableView` in to another `UIViewController` named as "secondViewcontroller"

I have used the below code but it is not working, It says property "discoveredInstanceTableView" not found ...Anybody please help me:

In the firstViewcontroller:

```
  IBOutlet UITableView *discoveredInstanceTableView;
```

In the Secondviewcontroller:

```
 firstViewcontroller *vc1 = [[firstViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstViewcontroller" bundle:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:vc1];
    [self.myTableview addSubview:vc1.discoveredInstanceTableView];
```

Comment: Did you synthesize the property of `discoveredInstanceTableView` in your `firstViewcontroller` ?

Comment: Can you show the code for the declaration of firstViewcontroller?

Comment: [from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-DontLinkElementID_9): «IMPORTANT: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.» As UITableView is a UIScrollView, this applies here as-well.

Comment: Nice reference and well explained @vikingosegundo !!

Answer (score 0):

declare in viewcontroller2

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *table;
```

create table in viewcontroller1

```
tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

while calling viewcontroller2 pass table to viewcontroller2

```
  ViewController2 *v2=[[ViewController2 alloc]init];
  v2.table=tableView;
  UINavigationController *navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:v2];
  [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in viewcontroller2 access the table using the global variable

```
[self.view addSubview:self.table];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is valid only if you curious to know why the above thing is not working answer would be

You are doing something that is not allowed, this can not be done as per the documentation.
However, If we forget about the right wrong approach, you probably adding a table view as a subview over a table view itself and I am sure you passing a table view to a table view which might not be allocated.

First think about the UITableView how it works? it simply a ScrollableView which display content over its cells.

Eventually would recommend you read about [TableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/)

**EDIT:** From the Above Comments

> IMPORTANT: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.» As UITableView is a UIScrollView, this applies here as well.

Possible Alternatives of displaying TableView inside the SecondViewController

- Use @Rajath Kornaya's Answer And In my opinion that is not right approach since whenever you required callback action like on cell tap, you want to display an alert(or something else), you can't get the delegate callback inside the SecondViewController

But there are so many other right approaches available, that you should follow up.

- Create a TableView separately either programmatically or through the XIB/Storyboard
- Add delegate and data source (methods which responds when something interesting happened e.g Cell going to populate called `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) to current SecondViewController
- Define all required data source methods and write proper code.
- If you required to do something on cell tap, add specific delegate method too.

But if you want to reuse the FirstViewController Class TableView simply create a CustomView and add TableView inside there and simply add that view to each view controller class.

I hope it may helps you!!!